Azure data Factory - data flow Translating accent characters to normal characters issue
I used translate(trim(BillingCity),'àáâãäåāăąÀÁÂÃÄÅĀĂĄèéêëēĕėęěÈÉÊËĒĔĖĘĚìíîïìĩīĭÌÍÎÏÌĨĪĬòóôõöøōŏőÒÓÔÕÖØŌŎŐùúûüũūŭůÙÚÛÜŨŪŬŮçćĉċčÇĆĈĊČñńņňÑŃŅŇ',
'aaaaaaaaaAAAAAAAAAeeeeeeeeeEEEEEEEEEiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooooooooOOOOOOOOOuuuuuuuuUUUUUUUUcccccCCCCCnnnnNNNN')
there is a data which contain 'ņ' it should replace with 'n' but the output was '?'. Why it happens? and Any better solution for this issue?
I tried regex_replace and replace but this get increases the line of code but also same result

I have tried the same expression in the derived column.
translate(trim(first_name),'àáâãäåāăąÀÁÂÃÄÅĀĂĄèéêëēĕėęěÈÉÊËĒĔĖĘĚìíîïìĩīĭÌÍÎÏÌĨĪĬòóôõöøōŏőÒÓÔÕÖØŌŎŐùúûüũūŭůÙÚÛÜŨŪŬŮçćĉċčÇĆĈĊČñńņňÑŃŅŇ', 'aaaaaaaaaAAAAAAAAAeeeeeeeeeEEEEEEEEEiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooooooooOOOOOOOOOuuuuuuuuUUUUUUUUcccccCCCCCnnnnNNNN')

You can see it's giving expected results for all the input characters.

You have mentioned that it is giving ? in your case. I have got similar results when the encoding in the source dataset is US-ASCII.

So, make sure you have UTF-8 encoding to get the correct results.


It was csv so there is encoding. What if we use delta format

Do you mean delta table in databricks? what is your source exactly here?
